# After page loading scroll to the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Want to ask how to do scrolling to the `<div>` element by pressing search submit button after the page loading finished? I'm guessing it needs input hidden ?

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#button").click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#elementtoScrollToID").offset().top
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

```
<form action="<?php echo $formURL ?>" method="post">
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="<?php echo $useAjax ? JText::_('COM_JEA_LIST_PROPERTIES') : JText::_('JSEARCH_FILTER_SUBMIT')?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="elementtoScrollToID" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Class Selector (".class")](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) as `button` is a class to element.

Use `$(".button")` instead of `$("#button")`. Also you need to use [attribute value selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) for `elementtoScrollToID`

*Complete Code*

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("[name=elementtoScrollToID]").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```